# Deep copy UIView subviews to one UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiview

I need to extract all nested subviews (from multiple views) and add them, with the correct positioning to one UIView 1 level deep.

```
NSArray*contentViews;    // views with complicated nesting of subViews
UIView *flatView;      // All the subviews but as simple subviews of the parent.

[self deepCopyAllSubviews:[contentViews[i++] subviews] to newView:flatView];
```

My problem is how do I find the correct origin in relation to flatView?

```
-(void) deepCopyAllSubviews:(NSArray*)subviews newView:flatView {

    [subviews enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {

        CGRect frame = [(UIView*)obj frame];

        frame.origin.x =  ??

        [(UIView *)obj setFrame:frame];

        [flatView addSubview:obj];

        NSArray *subs = [(UIView*)obj subviews];

        if ([subs count]>0) {

            [self deepCopyAllSubviews:subs newView:flatView];
        }
    }];
}
```

Comment: I am not getting your question but frame would give you x and y position relative to it's parent where bound will give x and y position in absolute manner.

Comment: Add the origin of a subview's frame to the origin of its parent's frame and the origin of its parent's parent's frame and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `UIView`'s conversion methods. For example, in your `???` line, try:

```
frame.origin = [((UIView *)obj).superview convertPoint:frame.origin toView:flatView];
```

If the original view is still attached to its original superview, and the flatView exists in the same window's hierarchy, these conversion methods will be able to get you the relative geometry that I think you're looking for.